# ExpressJS - req.files is undefined or empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an application in node.js that needs to upload pictures.  I have a route that renders the following view:

```
form(id="image-form", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    fieldset
        label(for="image") Image to Upload:
        input(type="file", id="image")

    input(class="btn btn-primary", name="submit", type="submit", value="Submit")
```

And, then, in my post route, I simply log the req.files object:

```
console.log(req.files);
```

Which returns an empty object:

```
{}
```

I've double checked that I'm using

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

per similar questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to set the `name` of the `<input>` as well:

```
input(type="file", id="image", name="image")
```

Without that, the `<form>` is skipping over it when submitting.